# Different results with matlab cumtrapz and scipy.integrate cumtrapz

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy

Im translating some matlab code to python code and debugging both codes i get a different result from a call to the `cumtrapz` function, i also verified that the input data of both is similar. This are the codes:

Python Code

```py
from numpy import zeros, ceil, array, mean, ptp, abs, sqrt, power
from scipy.integrate import cumtrapz

def step_length_vector(ics_y, fcs_y, acc_y, l, sf):
    step_length_m1 = zeros(int(ceil(len(ics_y)/2))-1) 

    for i in range(0, len(ics_y)-2, 2):
        av = acc_y[int(ics_y[i]):int(ics_y[i+2])+1]
        t = array(range(1, int((ics_y[i+2]-ics_y[i])+2)))/sf
        hvel = cumtrapz(t, av - mean(av), initial=0)
        h = cumtrapz(t, hvel - mean(hvel), initial=0)
        hend = ptp(h)
        sl = 6.8*(sqrt(abs(2*l*hend - hend**2)))
        step_length_m1[int(ceil(i/2))] = sl

    return step_length_m1
```

Matlab Code

```
function [StepLengthM1] = StepLengthVector(ICsY,FCsY,ACCY,l,sf)

        StepLengthM1 = zeros(1,ceil(length(ICsY)/2)-1);

        for i= 1:2:length(ICsY)-2
           av   = ACCY(ICsY(i):ICsY(i+2));           
           t    = (1:(ICsY(i+2)-ICsY(i))+1)/sf;
           hvel = cumtrapz(t,av-mean(av));      
           h    = cumtrapz(t,hvel-mean(hvel));
           hend = peak2peak(h);
           sl   = 6.8*(sqrt(abs(2*l*hend - hend.^2)));
           StepLengthM1(ceil(i/2)) = sl;
        end   
end
```

The `hvel` variable is different for both codes. Maybe im using wrong the `scipy` `cumtrapz` because i asume that the `initial` value that recives is `0`. In both cases the inputs `ics_y(ICsy)`, `fcs_y(FCsY)`, acc_y`(ACCY)` are one dimensional arrays and `l` and `sf` are scalars.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(If this question is about `cumtrapz`, you should simplify your tests to just a single call to `cumtrapz` with the same input arrays in matlab and Python.  Also, be sure you read the matlab and SciPy documentation of each function carefully.  The SciPy functions are typically not exact duplicates of the corresponding matlab function.)

The problem is that when you give both `x` and `y` values, the order in which they are given in matlab/octave is `x, y`, but in the SciPy version, it is `y, x`.

For example,

```
octave:11> t = [0 1 1.5 4 4.5 6]
t =

   0.00000   1.00000   1.50000   4.00000   4.50000   6.00000

octave:12> y = [1 2 3 -2 0 1]
y =

   1   2   3  -2   0   1

octave:13> cumtrapz(t, y)
ans =

   0.00000   1.50000   2.75000   4.00000   3.50000   4.25000
```

To get the same result with [`scipy.integrate.cumtrapz`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.cumtrapz.html):

```
In [22]: from scipy.integrate import cumtrapz                                                         

In [23]: t = np.array([0, 1, 1.5, 4, 4.5, 6])                                                         

In [24]: y = np.array([1, 2, 3, -2, 0, 1])                                                            

In [25]: cumtrapz(y, t, initial=0)                                                                    
Out[25]: array([0.  , 1.5 , 2.75, 4.  , 3.5 , 4.25])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That solves it. Maybe i misunderstood the matlab arguments from the docs.